# Error in Nim Game again

Tags: java, runtime, runtime-error

I wasn't sure if I should've created a new question for this...but now a new problem arises.
The program runs perfectly when the computer is executing in the so called "Smart Mode," but there is an error when the program runs in "Dumb Mode"

I keep getting an error whenever I get close to winning the game (Snickerdoodles, I just lost the game) when the computer is in Dumb mode...the error goes something like this:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
> at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:294)
> at GameOfNim.main(GameOfNim.java:62)
> ```

I understand that n must be positive in that instance, but I even have an if statement that tells the code what to do IF that actually happens...

Any solutions you guys have?

Oh, and here is the code again (I'm not including the Smart-mode method since this has nothing to do with it):

```
import java.util.*;
public class GameOfNim
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        Random num = new Random ();
        int numberLeft = num.nextInt(101-10) + 10;
        int computerMode = num.nextInt(2);
        int subtraction = numberLeft;
        boolean turn = num.nextBoolean();
        String computer = "";

        System.out.println ("The number you start out with is: " + numberLeft);
        System.out.println ("-------------------");

        if (computerMode == 0)
        {
            System.out.println ("The computer is in smart mode");
            System.out.println ("-------------------");
            computer = "Smart";
        }
        if (computerMode == 1)
        {
            System.out.println ("The computer is in dumb mode");
            System.out.println ("-------------------");
            computer = "Dumb";
        }

        while (numberLeft > 1)
        {
            if (turn == true)
            {
                System.out.println ("-------------------");
                System.out.println ("It is your turn...");
                System.out.printf ("Please enter the number you wish to take from the pile (Remember it has to be less than " + ((numberLeft/2) +1) + "): ");
                subtraction = in.nextInt();
                numberLeft -=subtraction;
                System.out.println ("The number left is " + numberLeft);
                turn = false;

            }
            if (turn ==false)
            {
                System.out.println ("-------------------");
                System.out.println ("It is the computer's turn...");
                if (computer.equals("Smart"))
                {
                    numberLeft = smartComputer(numberLeft);
                    System.out.println ("The number left is " + numberLeft);

                }

                if (computer.equals("Dumb"))
                {
                    if (numberLeft - num.nextInt(numberLeft/2) <= 1)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        numberLeft -= (num.nextInt(numberLeft/2 - 1) + 1);
                    }
                    System.out.println ("The number left is " + numberLeft);
                }
                turn = true;
            }
        }

        if (numberLeft <= 1)
        {
            if (turn = false)
            {
                System.out.println ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
                System.out.println ("You Win!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
                System.out.println ("You're horrible...you lost to a computer.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The exception message is telling you **exactly** what is wrong, you're passing a negative number into the `Random#nextInt(int i)` method. Solution 1: don't do this! Solution 2: Do read the exception messages critically as they can be **very** helpful if you do.

Comment: So....just get rid of the check?
But then, how would I make sure that it doesn't go negative?
Make a while loop that only makes it run while num > 0?

Comment: @PratikM `num.nextInt(/* int value should be > 0 */)`. Other wise throws `IllegalArgumentException`. check happens after you calculate the `numberleft` and `Exception` get thrown before that. You have to handle the condition when `numberLeft/2 - 1` calculates to `int <= 0`

Comment: I tried running this code, but somehow got stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: @Wusiji it seems to run fine for me

Answer (score 0):

```
if (numberLeft <= 1)
    {
        if (turn = false)
        {
            System.out.println ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
            System.out.println ("You Win!");
        }
    }
```

you have an assignment here instead of an equality check. Although I don't think that is the cause of the whole problem

Comment: I didn't even notice that! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This section of code looks sketchy

```
if (turn == true)
            {
                System.out.println ("-------------------");
                System.out.println ("It is your turn...");
                System.out.printf ("Please enter the number you wish to take from the pile (Remember it has to be less than " + ((numberLeft/2) +1) + "): ");
                subtraction = in.nextInt();
                numberLeft -=subtraction;
                System.out.println ("The number left is " + numberLeft);
                turn = false;

            }
            if (turn ==false)
            {
               ...
```

In the block of code that handles when it is the player's turn, you change the value of *numberLeft*, and also set *turn=false*. That means  that the test *turn==false* will be *TRUE*, and the block of code where the computer program generates a random integer will be entered.

You might try this instead:

```
else if (turn == false)
{
    ...
```

Comment: Ah. Thanks for that. Lol I never knew my code was so messed up.
But then again, it's to be expected, since I'm still learning to code Java.